# Change HTML Document Title from Form input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I am trying to change a HTML page's title based on form input. This is needed because the page will be printed as a PDF and we want it to be saved as the customer's name + caller.)

I know the following code will change the document's title.

```
onClick="document.title = "My new title";
```

But I'm trying to do something like:

```
onClick="document.title = document.getElementById("customerName").value +" " + "Caller" ;"
```

Here is an example form:

```
<form action="">
  <label for="customerName">Customer name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="customerName" name="customerName" ><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="document.title = document.getElementById("customerName").value +" " + "Caller" ;">
</form>
```

Comment: Your issue is related to your overusage of `"` within your markup.  `attr="something"with double quotes" in it"` is an html parsing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.title = document.getElementById('customerName').value +' ' + 'Caller' ;
```

Comment: So simple... I'm still learning JS and didn't even notice this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have quote issues. Also use the submit event instead of click

```js
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // remove if you DO want the form to submit
  document.title = document.getElementById("customerName").value + " " + "Caller";
})
```

```html
<form action="" id="form1">
  <label for="customerName">Customer name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="customerName" name="customerName"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To give you the answer just try this code and see what i did different :)

```js
let handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  document.title = document.getElementById("customerName").value + " " + "Caller";
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
  <label for="customerName">Customer name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="customerName" name="customerName"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Inline event handlers are not recommended - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64685703/295783) for a better way